# SnagIt image capture - when capturing image becomes bigger than area to capture - annoying

Tags: screenshot, screen-capture, image-capture

When trying to capture a region on a screen with Snagit - suddenly the area becones magnified and bigger than real size. Result  - not capable of capturing the whole visible region because of this magnifier. What can I change in the options to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Snagit, version 12, there is the **Show magnifier** option (Preferences) you should turn off to disable the magnifier which is causing you problems